# How to find out what databses are on a server programmaticaly?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Is there any way I could find out programmaticaly what databases exist on a server? It's because I would like to show user all available databases and allow him to choose the one he's interested in.

Comment: what kind of database ? it will probably be different for each type of DBMS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, "Which databases are on a specific instance of SQL Server", then the stored procedure `sp_databases` (accessible via Master) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

use Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo, it lets you query for servers and databases, specifically when you call SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers().

Answer (score 0):

- 2k5: `select * from sys.databases`
- 2k: `select * from sysdatabases`

Answer (score 0):

Would depend on which database you were referring to. Each db has their own way of querying these meta info.

Comment: question is tagged 'sqlserver'

Comment: That tag was added after the accepted answer had been accepted

Answer (score 0):

See [Three Way To List All Databases On Your Server](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Three_Way_To_List_All_Databases_On_Your_Server)